# Can't compile native module against electron instead of node.js

Tags: node.js, electron, node-gyp

I am writing a simple native module to use with electron app, but it compiles with the NODE_MODULE_VERSION 72 (node's version) instead of 73 (electron one). I used every possible step described [here](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules). electron-rebuild creates a folder structure bin/darwin-x64-73 (where 73 I suppose means module version), but upon requiring it from electron, app threw's with the same [error](https://pastebin.com/0dhMW2Sc)

Here's my simple binding.gyp:

```
{
    "targets": [
        {
            "target_name":"module_name",
            "sources":["path/to/module.cpp"],
        }
    ]
}
```

*and I guess inside build/config.gypi generated by node-gyp there is line: "node_module_version": 72, which is always the same no matter what method I try*

Also, is there a way to tell which NODE_MODULE_VERSION compiled module uses without crashing electron app with wrong one?

Comment: Did you try electron-rebuild instead of node-rebuild?

Comment: @LeonardoBuscemi, sorry, my bad. I did use electron-rebuild, just mistyped it in the question